# Capistrano fails to run bundle install when deploying to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rbenv

I've done multiple deployments with this app before. Made some changes recently, now the deployment fails with "Install missing gems with bundle install" and the following logs

```
bundle stderr: bash: line 1: 21748 Killed  $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet
```

and

```
DEBUG [d761e744] Command: cd /home/deploy/my_app/releases/20161222160000 && ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.2" ; $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --path /home/deploy/my_app/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
```

I can't figure out why this fails all of a sudden and what changed? Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that you changed Ruby version recently?

Comment: yes I did, but I'm not sure what I missed. Everything seems to be set to version 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

apparently I ran out of RAM, so it couldn't compile. Rebooting the server is a quick fix to free up some memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you changed the server Ruby version.

Whenever you use Ruby Managers and change the Ruby version, you must ensure that your remote server is switched over to the new Ruby version AND that you have the `bundler` gem installed using the new Ruby version.

If your `Gemfile` does not specify a Rails version, include this.

Once your server is running the new Ruby version and has `bundler` installed, then pushing code using Capistrano will cause a `bundle`, which will resolve dependency issues and install all the required gem under the new Ruby version.

Try this and let me know if you're having more issues.

Comment: yes I already did those things, doesn't seem to be the problem. Bundle install still fails

Comment: You should always include every error message with questions. If I remember correctly that error message says Cannot allocate memory, which would of easily gotten you an answer.

Comment: No there was no such error message mentioning memory at all.